# How do I turn off subtitles in Audience/Videos?

Tags: videos, audience, subtitles

Subtitles are in an external file.  I can change the file, but can't find a 'no subtitles' option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Comment: In this case there is an answer to the question - so I don't think this is a dupe.

Answer (score 10):

It's a bug in Audience and it's already reported on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/audience/+bug/1362910

P.S. If you've wandered to this post and saw this bug, and it affects you - please click "this bug affects me" on a launchpad to let developers know about the IPU