# How to fix drag and drop issue on elementary OS Freya?

Tags: release-freya, user-interface

After using Freya I have discovered there is an issue when dragging and dropping icons. After that, the icon combines with the mouse pointer and moves with it.

I have found that this issue can be solved by going to the lock screen and logging in again.

I'd like to have a permanent solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be
[reported on Launchpad](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/387/) so that
developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Comment: @DanielForé It's not a duplicate - http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/72/closing-as-a-duplicate-is-not-the-way-to-close-bug-questions

Comment: the bug was already reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1442431) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1390625)

Comment: The meta post has been deleted since, great -.-

Comment: To clarify, this question isn't a duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers) because it isn't asking about if this is a bug, it's specifically asking for a workaround, as it already lists one.

Comment: @quassy I could undelete it, but I'd be concerned about that users privacy (people have the right to be forgotten), so this is the canonical meta question http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/55/should-a-question-about-a-bug-be-closed-or-deleted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update kernel and X to **vivid** fix this for me. This became possible after Ubuntu 14.04.3 release. More info on [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Update:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

**Warning!** Be careful and attentive to this, the system can fail. If you use apps with 32-bit libs (Skype, Steam, Wine), first remove them and install again after update. Check packages that will be removed before pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>. In my case, everything went well and it looks like this:

```
maxim@ProBook:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgbm1-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid
  libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libllvm3.6 libxatracker2-lts-vivid
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25 linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-generic-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-vivid-tools xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
  gpointing-device-settings touchfreeze firmware-linux
Recommended packages:
  libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-vivid
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-lts-utopic libgbm1-lts-utopic
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
  libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic
  libopenvg1-mesa-lts-utopic libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-utopic
  libxatracker2-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-utopic
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-utopic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid libgbm1-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid
  libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libllvm3.6 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
  libxatracker2-lts-vivid linux-generic-lts-vivid linux-headers-3.19.0-25
  linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid
  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-vivid
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-vivid
0 upgraded, 44 newly installed, 39 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 308 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:** This has been fixed in the latest release of elementary OS. Please download and install the latest release from [our home page](http://elementary.io).

---

I've voted to close this as a duplicate of the [How to Report an Issue](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers) question.

This is a pretty well known bug and it affects Ubuntu as well as elementary OS. The Ubuntu hardware team is hard at work on this issue, but there is no permanent fix available at the moment. If there was, it would have gone out as an update already :)

You can follow the issue [in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1390625)

Hopefully there will be a fix available along with the new hardware stack in August of 2015.

Comment: If you have voted to close, there is no need to answer - if the duplicate question doesn't explain generally enough then the duplicate needs to be improved. This content should have been a comment. And in this case, the duplicate feature is being abused - really this should be a custom off topic reason.

Comment: @DanielForé If you feel the need to answer, then you shouldn't close as duplicate. Closing as a duplicate is for the cases where “that's a bug, report it” is all the information you want to convey. If you want to expand on the history of the bug, on possible workarounds, etc. then answer and don't close.

Comment: The deleted meta post?...

Answer (score 6):

On [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1430587) the following fixes had been suggested:

> Fixing this problem is rather too easy. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and use the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Source: http://itsfoss.com/invisible-mouse-cursor-ubuntu-1310/

Or alternatively:

> Actually.
>   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
>   didn't work for me. But as soon as I changed that false to true, it was fixed.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1430587/comments/9

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I use the Switch Display button (F4 or my laptop) to get back to normal.

I don't think there is a permanent fix to this bug (that was already reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1442431) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1390625)).

Comments under the ubuntu bug say that an upgrade above kernel 3.16 may fix it, while [another comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1390625/comments/45) denies this; other comments say that installing `xserver-xorg` may also be a solution.

I have not tested these possible fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is clear ("its a bug!") the workaround might come handy. For some reason moving cursor to the bottom-right corner erases this ghost following my pointer. Not much of a solution but still much better than logging off. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: My fix is to click the Cycle Display key (on my laptop it's F4)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the only kind of permanent solution is to keep icon zoom at 1. Anything greater exposes you to the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution proposed by dromnia86 on https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/34dm4t/fixrestart_corrupted_mouse_after_dragging/

It worked nicely for my machine.

## Create the file 20-intel.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

## Paste the following into the file and save it:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```