# Drag and drop results in corrupted cursor with artifacts

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

If i copy a file by dragging and dropping from a folder to the sidebar folder shortcut, I end up with the cursor being an artifact - two cursor icons with the thumbnail of the pic or video I just dragged.
(I cannot screenshot it as the cursor does not appear in a screenshot)
Does anyone else have this issue? 
Is there a way I can turn off thumbnail previews whilst dragging? 
*my cursor theme is unchanged - it is still elementary*

Comment: This is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1390625 and will be fixed with the next release of freya 0.3.1. This will happen soon.

Comment: For your next question: Please choose a meaningful title and use the search function first, there is a very similar question on here already: [How to fix drag and drop issue on elementary OS Freya?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/499/68), which includes some temporary workarounds.

Comment: Thanks @quassy I did see the other one, but it mentioned ICONS and not thumbnail views, so I was not sure that it was the same.