# HDMI Display not working consistently

Tags: release-freya

Sometimes when I connect my laptop to my TV, my Built-In Display turns off but my TV is turned on, but in the settings it says that both are on. Also, when I try to change the settings (off -> on), the setting switches back. For example, when I click on the button to enable one of the displays, the switch turns back to "off". I have the Intel Graphics Driver installed. I'm on 0.3 Freya.

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be
[reported on Launchpad](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/387/) so that
developers can see, track and fix these issues.