# Slingshot + hot corner opening each 2nd time only

Tags: slingshot

I've configured left-top corner to be the Hot Corner to open Slingshot. Weird thing is, it opens only each second time, while every first time it opens and instantly closes.

To let you know what I'm talking about I've recorded a video and uploaded it to youtube: https://youtu.be/UxLN0WoXeEw

Hot corner configuration was performed via GUI, just like on a screenshot below:

[image: hot corner configuration]

I tried to launch slingshot from CLI in order to grab some debug output, but it doesn't throw anything in there. Tried to strace and understood it's no good :D Also it doesn't seem like slingshot is crashing - PID doesn't change.

Any ideas whether this is a glitch due to my misconfiguration, or more like a bug I should report on Launchpad? I've already searched the launchpad and didn't find anything like this, that is why I thought I might be the only one suffering here because my hands are not properly aligned.

Comment: I can reproduce and can confirm that this is unintended behaviour. You should probably [file this as a bug](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers/388#388). If you post a link here I will confirm it.

Comment: Lewis thanks for confirmation! Will do right away

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report, not a question.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be a bug.
Submitted it to Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/slingshot/+bug/1474830

Lewis, thanks for confirmation