# Why don't clicks on links in Thunderbird automatically open my web browser?

Tags: applications

Using elementary OS 0.3 Freya (64-bit). I use Chromium as my browser and Thunderbird as my e-mail client.

When I click on a url in Thunderbird, I notice the url is passed to Chromium, but control isn't transferred to Chromium.  I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle to Chromium.  Very annoying.

Why doesn't elementary OS automatically switch to Chromium, when I click on a link in Thunderbird?  Why the extra keystrokes?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this issue is limited to Thunderbird / Chromium but instead related to a known [GTK+ bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752000) inherited from mutter that affects gala. Fortunately after several years it appears a possible fix may be [forthcoming](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1220179).

There are several other instances ([[1]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1462933),[[2]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1014120)) of annoying focus issues in the elementary OS bug tracker which the above fix will hopefully resolve.

I would suggest you mark the appropriate bugs as 'Affecting me' on the elementary OS bug tracker or opening a new one if your feel yours is in fact different.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad to know it's a known problem and may be addressed.