# Use Alt + F4 to shut down elementary OS

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shutdown

I am afraid this would be hard to achieve however I'll try to ask.

I was used from other systems like Windows or other distros that when you have multiple applications opened and you want to shutdown your computer, then you just keep pressing Alt + F4 (and either saving or discarding sessions from programs you have opened before) until you reach the dialog which offers you shutdown.

However pressing Alt + F4 when no applications are opened in elementary OS does nothing, is there a way how to change the settings to have this kind of behavior?

Comment: I do not believe it would be possible to both keep the current window-closing behaviour and also trigger a shutdown within elementary.

Comment: it would be possible in gala which also handels the other known hotkeys. but perhaps gala doesn't track active windows than it would be hard.
it would always need to be implemented code wise

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to leave this as a comment so I'll leave this as an answer: This appears to be a feature request. Those should be done on Launchpad so developers can properly track and discuss it. If you don't know how to file a feature request, this might help: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers

Comment: Thanks, I have filled a bug report so hopefully it's going to find it's way to the Elementary :)