# How can I change the position of notification bubble?

Tags: release-freya, notifications

In Luna I used `com.canonical.notify-osd gravity` setting [(like in Ubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186419/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-the-ubuntu-notifications) to change the position of notification bubble.

Since Freya seems to have its own notification bubbles, this setting don't exist anymore.

How can I change the position of notification bubble in Freya?

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a setting for it in the freya gala notification plugin.

You can report it as a feature request.
[How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Comment: okay, thank you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1480258