# Why does the mouse pointer move as if it is on a block of ice?

Tags: mouse

I have been trying out elementary OS on a HP stream 11 laptop and it is working great, but what is the deal with the mouse pointer? I am using a USB corded mouse (but have also tried the trackpad) and the mouse pointer moves around as if it is skating on ice.

When I stop moving the mouse, the pointer keeps moving slightly until it finally stops. Why is it not stopping immediately after I stop moving the mouse?

Comment: Did you maybe try another mouse, or another surface? I'm not experiencing that problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Comment: This seems like its an issue with your mouse or the surface you are using it on rather than an issue with elementary OS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a hardware issue

Comment: @Gabriel Adam wrote that he also tried his trackpad. It doesn't sound like a hardware problem...

Comment: I have to agree that if this has been tried with two input devices, it's not a hardware issue. Maybe still too specialised (unlikely to be answered if no-one can reproduce), but not hardware specific.

Comment: Btw, [hardware questions are not off-topic.](http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/110/are-hardware-specific-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

try installing trackpad software, this solved my problem
* cat /proc/bus/input/devices
* I had to use a glidepoint driver

Comment: Could you add some more info describing the specific process you went through to get this new driver and so forth?

Comment: if u carefully check the output my output in the terminal. Mines looked like this  N: Name="GlidePoint Virtual Touchpad" so I started looking for my specific driver for ubuntu 14.04 (as EOS Freya is based on)

Comment: Ok, so I ran your command, grepping for touchpad drivers like so: `$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i touch`. This was the output: `N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`. Thus far, I haven't had too much luck on google for finding this software and the installation process thereof. Do you have any further advice on this?

Comment: synaptics touchpad driver linux ubuntu 14.04, googled for it, first one

Comment: Sándor Bolla, thanks for the advice. I finally got around to doing this, and this synaptiks driver seems to have fixed the issue. +1

Comment: Btw, for anyone having the same issue, here's the article that I used to solve this issue and install the synaptiks driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/453876/how-to-install-synaptiks-on-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04.