# I have some problems with OS beta. Help please

Tags: release-freya, touchpad

After I have installed elementary OS. The laptop seems to have some kind of lag and the touchpad also doesn´t work.

```
CPU: AMD A10-5750M Quad-Core @ 2.50 Ghz
Graphics: Radeon HD Graphics
RAM: 6 GB
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You mention "beta" in your title. Where did you download the OS from? http://elementary.io is the only official vendor.

Answer (score 4):

There's no beta version at the moment. There's only the stable Freya (0.3) version available on [elementary.io](http://elementary.io).

Please, install elementary OS from the official source. If the problems are still there, then see this: [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)