# How to automatically switch to connected Bluetooth headset and enable A2DP mode?

Tags: sound, bluetooth

**Default state:**

1. Enable bluetooth
2. Connect to paired bluetooth headset
3. Sound > Output > "Device for sound output" remains "Speakers - Built-in Audio"
4. Switch "Device for sound output" to bluetooth headset
5. Set Profile from HSP/HFP to A2DP

**Desired state:**

1. Enable bluetooth
2. Connect to paired bluetooth headset
3. Sound > Output > Device for sound output is automatically switched to the bluetooth headset
4. Profile is automatically switched from HSP/HFP to A2DP

EDITED AS NO OTHER APPARENT WAY TO ANSWER AN INVALIDLY CLOSED QUESTION:

```
su -
```

```
printf "# 2015-10-23
# Autoconnect to audio sink as soon as presented
# source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8409/autoconnecting-bluetooth-devices
load-module module-switch-on-connect" >> /etc/pulse/default.pa && service pulseaudio restart && exit
```

Testing:

- Onboard Bluetooth control state: on
- Powered on *previously paired* Bluetooth headset
- Watched funny cat video on Youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, this is probably a feature request. Quite simply, the code for detecting and implementing this action does not exist, and likely won't appear until a bug has been filed and a fix released.

> Questions about bugs and feature requests are off-topic because they cannot be resolved via Q&A. For more information on how to report issues, see [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Comment: Thanks Lewis! Which would be the most appropriate bug tracker to address this request?

Comment: Use the [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+filebug) link from the linked answer, and select "elementary OS" from the dropdown (since bluetooth doesn't really exist there yet).

Comment: I filed the [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1493051) for future reference.