# When I try to access the keyboard settings, the app just closes. How do I access the keyboard settings?

Tags: settings, keyboard

[image: the result of gnome-control-center keyboard]

I'm trying to open the keyboard settings from the System Settings app, and the app just closes down. Every other item opens just fine.

> elementary os 0.3 freya
>
> Linux 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64

Please let me know what other info I can provide. I don't know what details will be helpful in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed elementary-tweaks per chance? (I see `Tweaks.vala` in your terminal output) Unfortunately while a great application, it is reported to cause issues and is [not recommend](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/elementarys-stance-on-elementary-tweaks). This might be one of those issues? Try uninstalling it and see if the problem persists. If that fixes it I'd suggest posting a bug to the elementary-tweaks [bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~mpstark).

**Edit 1:**

Just for clarification, `gnome-control-center` is a bash script that redirects to `switchboard`, which is the actual name of the *System Settings* app in elementary OS.

Upon further inspection of your terminal output, it shows a segfault on line 20, which is where the redirection takes place. The actual command to open the keyboard settings dialog is `switchboard keyboard`. Run that command directly and see if it gives any additional clues. If there is nothing obvious there, run it with the -d flag to show additional debug information. `switchboard -d keyboard`.

You could try to reinstall switchboard and the keyboard plugin with-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall switchboard switchboard-plug-keyboard
```

If a reinstall doesn't help, it is time to hit the *switchboard-plug-keyboard* bug tracker. See [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers) for best practices in lodging bug reports. I notice there are [several](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-keyboard?field.searchtext=crash&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=) existing bugs related to crashing on there already that may be possible duplicates of yours.

Please update your question with the `-d` output and a link to the bug report. Also consider including a link to this question in your bug report in case someone else comes along and solves your problem here.

Comment: Hello @elmato, I uninstalled elementary tweaks and tried the terminal command you suggested. I'm still getting the same behavior in system settings. The new output in the terminal is: [_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:05:45.656706] Application.vala:155: System Settings version: 2.0
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:05:45.656756] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-38-generic
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: line 20:  2526 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) switchboard $switchboard_options $requested_plug

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I had the same problem, and this worked for me. Clicking that will reset the monitor config to default

Notice the `key file contains key "Monitor" in group "PlankDockPreferences"` in your terminal output? I'm not sure, but I am guessing it's because I sometimes plug in a 2nd monitor and I shift the displays around and Tweaks is trying to save it. After I unplug the monitor the configurations causes an error and quits.