# Switch board option keyboard core dumped (Segment fault) with normal user

Tags: release-freya, keyboard

When i try to open keyboard through terminal

```
~$ switchboard keyboard
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 00:45:42.319800] Application.vala:155: System Settings version: 2.0
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 00:45:42.319880] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.19.0-32-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 00:45:42.333001] Tweaks.vala:229: Activating Tweak plug
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 00:45:42.375612] PlankSettings.vala:165: Key file contains key 'Monitor' in group 'PlankDockPreferences' which has a value that cannot be interpreted.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381051] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381109] System Settings will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381182] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381216] System Settings will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381354] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381383] System Settings will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381445] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:45:42.381472] System Settings will not function properly.
/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: line 20: 11091 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) switchboard $switchboard_options $requested_plug
```

Occured `Segmentation fault      (core dumped)`
Already try this [duplicate](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/when-i-try-to-access-the-keyboard-settings-the-app-just-closes-how-do-i-access) but don't have answer.
But when i try to open by this command `gksu gnome-control-center keyboard` it's working ok.

```
$ gksu switchboard keyboard
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(gksu:11120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:11120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:11120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:11120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:11120): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 00:46:35.760625] Application.vala:155: System Settings version: 2.0
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 00:46:35.760673] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.19.0-32-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 00:46:35.777143] Tweaks.vala:229: Activating Tweak plug
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 00:46:35.780529] GtkSettings.vala:48: Error loading GTK+ Keyfile settings.ini: No such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 00:46:35.780583] GtkSettings.vala:69: Error getting GTK+ int setting: Key file does not have group 'Settings'
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824232] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824277] System Settings will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824346] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824375] System Settings will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824499] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824528] System Settings will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824589] [GLib] g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 00:46:35.824616] System Settings will not function properly.
```

Can u guys explain and fix this problem
I'm using Freya

Comment: what is your exact Q. What's the difference in those two commands,Isn't it? or something?

Comment: first command can't open keyboard ( core dumped ). second command can

Comment: I'm guessing you're either installing elementary tweaks or have run this as root which has set some incorrect permissions.