# How can I fix the battery icon?

Tags: battery

The battery icon doesn't change with the time. I never know when my battery is near to finish. Even if I plug in the energy, the icon doesn't change.

Comment: This is probably a bug in the hardware support, you need to indicate precisely what hardware you have (e.g. the brand and the exact model of your laptop). But not here: this is a question and answer site, not the place to report bugs. Please see [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Comment: ASUS Ultrabook S46CA-BRA-WX160H com Intel Core 3 i7 6GB 1TB

Comment: Are you using any icon theme, or the default elementary icons?

Comment: I'm using the default elementary icons.