# maya geary integration

Tags: pantheon-mail, calendar

In my daily work-flow, I need to create events out of mails. (Meaning I can right click on the mail and have the option to create an event out of it). Best with date recognition (meaning while creating the event, dates that are found in mails are suggested as event dates) an that the created events refer back to the mails (meaning I can click on a link in the event and the mail opens in Geary).
Both possible under Mac Os x on my hackintosh.
Any suggestion how to set that up?

Comment: I think it is unlikely this can just be added on, and is more of a feature request. This question explains how to report bugs and feature requests: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers