# Usually when i'm going to install fonts the system breaks down !

Tags: fonts

When i go to install some ttf font (i didn't tryed installing open fonts) the system breaks down... sometimes the installation is fine and everything works correctly. Could be a pkg problem? or something like that? any solution?

Comment: There currently is no real sollution for this. You could go to the bug report page and click the "this bug affects me too" button, so they know a lot of people have this issue. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/1124450

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the pre-install and post-install scripts inside the package, if you are installing a `.deb` package:

```
dpkg -x package.deb
```

You can install fonts this way:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/my-fonts
sudo cp /path-to-ttf-file /usr/share/fonts/my-fonts
sudo fc-cache -v
```