# Scratch editor: see cursor position

Tags: code

How can I see the actual cursor position? Usually, other editors use the [status bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_bar) for this, but I can not find where is the option to enable it (even checked with the dconf editor).

Is there a plugin for this?

(I'm on ElementaryOS, Freya)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such option or plugin. You should probably file an issue report against Scratch. See this other StackExchange post: [How can I report an issue with elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers)