# No file names in multi tasking view

Tags: hot-corners

When I open multiple files using other linux operating systems if I go the the hot corner and it is set to multi tasking all the files are displayed with a name under or above each file. If I do the same in Elementary all the files are displayed but no name, does anybody know if there is a setting to add file names so that I can see which each file is in multi tasking view>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't currently a way to add titles to multitasking view.

If you'd like, you can file a feature request on [Gala](https://launchpad.net/gala), the elementary OS window manager. For more on filing bugs and feature requests, see [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-with-elementary-os-to-the-developers).