# Where can I report bugs to elementary patches of Epiphany?

Tags: release-juno, epiphany, github

I'm looking for a place to track development and report issues with the patches to [epiphany](/questions/tagged/epiphany) browser, that were made by elementary devs. Epiphany in elementary is not vanilla, however I cannot find any repo where the patches are made. Can someone please point me to the repo?

In particular I'm using Epiphany also on Ubuntu 18.04 (same version - `bionic`), but some stuff works only in Ubuntu version and not in elementary (most notably some shortcuts, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [here](https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues), I understood what you need but I really don't know if that is the place you are looking for. Either way they should help you better

https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: It's already reported at https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues/17 anyway.

Comment: yes, I found it there too, added my comments

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, they were quite helpful. I'm adding another one that I just found, in case somebody else is looking for it too (e.g. future me):

## GNOME Gitlab

There is a **elementary OS** tag in issues of the gitlab repository of Epiphany:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/issues?label_name[]=5.+elementary+OS

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a place to track development...

For tracking development, I'm not sure about GitHub but you can check Launchpad here:
https://code.launchpad.net/~zhanming/elementaryos/epiphany

There's also development code here:
https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/os-patch-epiphany-browser-bionic

For reporting bugs, I would suggest reading the answer here: [How can I report an issue or request a feature for elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-or-request-a-feature-for-elementary-os-to-the-develope)

Comment: Thanks, however I see only commits from 2016 and Loki cycle.

Comment: I updated my response.

Comment: Thanks. I can still only see patches from March, nothing more recent. Also I did not find any way to report bugs, only to link existing bugs. I think I should rephrase the question as bug reports are more important to me than raw code.