# Appcenter popup error on each time and few others problems to launch programs

Tags: updates, applications, appcenter

I encounter an error each time I go in the Appcenter with updates, here is the resume :

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (non-free/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
E: http://apt.last.fm/debian stable InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not resolve 'apt.last.fm')
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (non-free/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target CNF (non-free/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/grabli66-r/eos/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

**Then, there are a few programs that I cannot launch at all like Steam, Nicehash, Rambox and few others which fail at launch.**

**Moreover, Last.fm is ok but I cannot log in without an error like :**

```
Couldn't connect to the internet to verify your user details.
If you use a proxy ...
```

I got no proxy there.

What could I do now ? It seems exhaustive.

Regards.

Comment: It seems exhaustive because they seem to be multiple different issues. You should split them into several topics. Also see [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-or-request-a-feature-for-elementary-os-to-the-develope)

Answer (score 1):

Remove in terminal E: PPA:grabli66-r/eos

`sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:grabli66-r/eos`

or edit /etc/apt/sources.list then:

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get update`

If needed grabli66-r/eos add PPA again:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grabli66-r/eos`

Comment: Hello JarekBaran and thanks for your help. I did the thing but there's still a box with thesame errors I guess.