# mac address of bluetooth device seen no name is seen

Tags: bluetooth

mac address of bluetooth device seen no name is seen in juno

I tried restarting the bluetooth services but all I see is mac addresses. Screenshot attached

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I report an issue or request a feature for elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-or-request-a-feature-for-elementary-os-to-the-develope)

Comment: This looks like a bug and should be [reported](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-bluetooth/issues) - try searching first if there is no similar bug already reported ;)

Comment: @jena, Your participation is much appreciated Please let me inform you that questions about bugs and feature requests are meant to be closed as such, not **duplicate**. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Hasan Sorry, I was just following [this accepted answer](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/should-a-question-about-a-bug-be-closed-or-deleted).

Comment: @jena Its okay. Actually since then there's been some changes to the forum and we have a cause in the option that is dedicated for bugs and feature requests. If you click on close button and select off-topic you will see first option says "Questions about bugs and feature requests are off-topic because they cannot be resolved via Q&A.......". Please use this one from now on. And I think we need to resolve the conflict, keep an eye on the meta, I will create a thread to discuss or explain this. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had that issue to. Sometimes depending on the device it shows the name but only method I’ve tried is just clicking one until the device connects

Comment: this advice sounds hazardous!