# How to Search for an app by starting to type on the desktop While 'show all open windows' is displayed

Tags: gnome, launcher, hot-corners, desktop-environment

How do I search for an app by starting to type on the desktop while the 'show all open windows' is displayed. e.g similar to gnome-shell top left hot corner in which you can just start typing an app name and it will display matches. I know clicking on the applications shortcut allows that, but it is an unnecessary step. Basically, how to I mimic the gnome shell type functionality. I've been using gnome-shell for years and can't unlearn this and can't live without it.

I've managed to set the top left corner as a hot corner for 'display all open windows', how do I now make the system start listening for keyboard strokes to search for applications without adding another click or keyboard stroke.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by now, maybe opening a freature request or searching them for the topic would give more insight, if it comes or not.

[How can I report an issue or request a feature for elementary OS to the developers?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-can-i-report-an-issue-or-request-a-feature-for-elementary-os-to-the-develope)